# Refatoração: Quando um método é "grande demais"?

Tags: python, estilo-de-codificação, método, refatoração

Estou com um projeto que "recupera" certas informações de uma página HTML, faz um *parse* com ajuda do Beautiful Soup e devolve os valores em forma de *dictionary*, para que em outro método eu gere um objeto JSON.

O problema é que pela peculiaridade da página, muito mal escrita e com excesso de tags, além de problemas com a organização das próprias informações, eu preciso tratar tudo com muito uso de laços e condicionais. O método atual tem 91 linhas.

Eu não consigo separar logicamente esses blocos de código em outros métodos, tudo me parece "parte de uma mesma operação". Fica ainda mais difícil porque também não parece que sejam úteis em outra situação.

Alguém tem alguma sugestão de quando e como posso dividir meu código?

Como exemplo, um método que fiz para "brincar", que compartilha do mesmo problema (pra deixar menos estranho, explico: ele pega as informações de uma página de cardápio do RU da minha universidade):

```
def parse_cardapios(self):

    """Interpreta as tabelas de cardápio no site do restaurante"""

    pag = urllib2.urlopen(self.url + '/' + self.campus).read();
    soup = BeautifulSoup(pag)
    resultado = []

    # Percorre as refeições e suas respectivas tabelas de cardápio

    nomes_ref = soup.find('section', id='post-content').find_all('h2')
    tabelas_card = soup.find('section', id='post-content').find_all('table')

    for ref, tab in zip(nomes_ref, tabelas_card):

        refeicao = tratar_chave(ref)

        # Percorre todos os dias disponíveis

        nome_colunas = tab.find_all('th')
        linhas = tab.find_all('tr', class_=True)

        for lin in linhas: # Cada linha é um dia diferente

            dia_repetido = False # Para controlar a repetição

            obj_refeicoes = {refeicao: {}}
            obj_temp = {'data': '', 'refeicoes': {}}

            # Percorre cada dado

            celulas = lin.find_all('td')

            for meta, dado in zip(nome_colunas, celulas):

                meta = tratar_chave(meta)
                dado = tratar_valor(dado)

                if meta == 'data':

                    dado = dado.translate(None, 'aábcçdefghijklmnopqrstuvzwxyz- ,')

                    if not resultado:
                        obj_temp['data'] = dado

                    else:
                        for r in resultado:
                            if r['data'] == dado:
                                dia_repetido = True
                                r['refeicoes'].update(obj_refeicoes)
                                break

                        else:
                            obj_temp['data'] = dado

                else:
                    obj_refeicoes[refeicao].update({meta: dado})
                    obj_temp['refeicoes'].update(obj_refeicoes)

            if not dia_repetido:
                resultado.append(obj_temp)

    # Junta as refeições vegetarianas no mesmo cardápio que as outras

    for r in resultado:
        for s in r['refeicoes'].keys():
            if '-vegetariano' in s:
                veg = {}
                for t in r['refeicoes'][s].keys():
                    if not '-vegetariano' in t:
                        veg.update({t + '-vegetariano': r['refeicoes'][s][t]})

                    else:
                        veg.update({t: r['refeicoes'][s][t]})

                sem_sufixo = s.replace('-vegetariano', '')
                r['refeicoes'][sem_sufixo].update(veg)

        for u in r['refeicoes'].keys():
            if '-vegetariano' in u:
                del r['refeicoes'][u]

    return dict({'campus': self.campus, 'dia-cardapio': resultado})
```

Comment: Poste seu código @Matheus

Comment: Talvez dividir pelo que está sendo extraido em cada parte. `extractProductInfo()`, `extractDescriptionBody()`, `extractComments()`, etc. Também pode ser possivel escrever o que você está fazendo com menos linhas. Difícil dizer sem ver o código.

Comment: Se não há duplicação de código (ou seja, se as operações executadas dentro do método não se repetem em nenhum outro lugar) não é tão pressuroso ficar quebrando em métodos menores. Fossem 1000 linhas, talvez...

Comment: Eu concordo que seria bom você postar ao menos uma parte do seu código. A sua pergunta é muito bacana e relevante, mas está muito ampla e propensa a receber opiniões como resposta. Se você postar o código talvez receba respostas mais diretas sobre formas de melhorá-lo. :)

Comment: Adicionei um código para exemplo (:

Comment: Quando ele está fazendo mais de uma coisa.

Comment: @RenatoDinhaniConceição, isso é meio que consenso, né? :p Ademais:
"Eu não consigo separar logicamente esses blocos de código em outros métodos, tudo me parece "parte de uma mesma operação". Fica ainda mais difícil porque também não parece que sejam úteis em outra situação."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Essa pergunta é bem relativa. Tem autores que recomendam 20 linhas, mas toleram até 100. Outros afirmam que alguns métodos podem sim consumir até 100~200 linhas e nem por isso deixam de ser tão facilmente compreensíveis como os que tem menos linhas.

Na prática, todos dizem o mesmo: quanto menor a quantidade de linhas por método, é melhor, mas não vale a pena fazer isso a um nível em que uma parte do código não pode ser diminuída.

A maioria dos meus métodos ficam entre 30~80 linhas, mas alguns pouquíssimos chegam próximos de umas 200 ou mais e nem por isso eu refratoro caso parte desse método maior não possa ser reutilizada em outros métodos.

**Update (após adição de código na pergunta)**

Removi espaços em branco e documentação e seu código deu 54 linhas, de operações que fazem sentido juntas. Definitivamente no seu exemplo não vejo fortes motivos para dividir em mais métodos se isso não vai permitir que o códigos divididos sejam reutilizados em outras áreas.

**Lembre-se quando os autores sugerem um limite máximo de linhas, eles desconsideram linhas em branco e comentários, e ainda assim as linhas são separadas por linhas lógicas**. Se o cara aninhar vários ifs em uma só linha isso contaria como varias linhas.

Comment: Com certeza, uma resposta esclarecedora. Tentei reduzir o método à lógica da extração das informações e até tarefas simples, como remover acentos, fiz questão de separar em outro método. O que me leva a outra pergunta... que acho que foge do escopo desta, então perguntarei em outro momento.

Answer (score 4):

Não li o método, mas métodos de classes, no contexto da programação orientada a objetos, devem sempre oferecer uma única funcionalidade. Dessa forma, sua aplicação fica mais desacoplada, os métodos ficam mais independentes e os componentes tẽm mais chances de serem reaproveitados.

Assim, não acho que exista um "limite ideal" para tamanhos de classes e métodos. O ideal é que sua metodologia de desenvolvimento siga os "cinco primeiros princípios" –também conhecidos como SOLID– que são os cinco princípios básicos para o design de uma aplicação orientada a objetos, a saber:

- S - Single responsibility principle - a class should have only a single responsibility
- O - Open/closed principle - “software entities … should be open for extension, but closed for modification”.
- L - Liskov substitution principle - “objects in a program should be replaceable with instances of their subtypes without altering the correctness of that program”. See also design by contract.
- I - Interface segregation principle - “many client-specific interfaces are better than one general-purpose interface.”
- D - Dependency inversion principle - one should “Depend upon Abstractions. Do not depend upon concretions.”

Fonte: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_(object-oriented_design)

Comment: Foi uma boa ter citado o SOLID, sintetiza alguns conceitos que podem passar despercebidos.

Comment: @rodrigorigotti muito boa sua resposta! Eu centrei em LLOC, porém o pessoal deveria considerar a sua também

Answer (score 3):

Tem pelo menos dois motivos fortes para se quebrar um método em outros métodos menores: reusabilidade e legibilidade. No seu caso, você menciona que não vai reutilizar esse código em outros lugares. Esse argumento pode também mudar à medida que você quebrar em blocos menores, reaproveitando certos algoritmos.

Especialmente no seu caso, a legibilidade poderia ser muito melhorada. Dentro de cada *for* praticamente você tem um comentário dizendo o que ele faz. Comentários são frágeis demais para isso. Se você criar um método acessório para cada *for*, por exemplo, você eliminaria os comentários, tornando o código auto-descritivo.

Por exemplo, seu método principal poderia ficar:

```
def parse_cardapios(self):

    nomes_ref, tabelas_card = carrega_refeicoes()

    return percorre_refeicoes(nomes_ref, tabelas_card)
```

Bem mais legível, na minha opinião.

Answer (score 2):

Uma regra geral é que se um refatoramento puder tornar o código mais simples, menos complexo, mais fácil de entender e manter, ele deve ser feito. O ideal é criar boas abstrações, coesas, com baixo acoplamento. Dentro desse contexto é que deve-se avaliar se um método deve ser refatorado ou não. Às vezes a solução não é trivial. Métodos que têm longos trechos envolvendo condicionais, por exemplo, requerem uma mudança de paradigma para o refatoramento (ex: substituição por estratégias que usam polimorfismo, transferindo a responsabilidade dos blocos para objetos individuais) Há também a possibilidade de analisar os métodos devido à sua complexidade ciclomática. Ferramentas como o PMD, Checkstyle, Sonar, fazem isso e são úteis para descobrir métodos que devem ser revisados.

(Esta resposta foi um tanto subjetiva devido à pergunta também ser. Envie trechos do seu código identificando as suas dúvidas de forma mais objetiva para que possamos discutir soluções mais práticas)

Comment: "Uma regra geral é que se um refatoramento puder tornar o código mais simples, menos complexo, mais fácil de entender e manter, ele deve ser feito. (...) Às vezes a solução não é trivial." Vou imprimir numa etiqueta e colar no meu monitor.

Answer (score 2):

Essa pergunta é realmente muito relativa. Depende muito da opinião de cada um. 
No código que você postou acima eu separaria por etapas, você mesmo já separou, usando comentários, ou seja, faria uma função para percorrer as refeições, uma para percorrer os dias, etc.
É realmente difícil de dizer quando um método é grande demais, mesmo essas definições de quantidade de linhas podem não ser tão corretas, acho que só a experiência é que vai te a ajudar a julgar isso de maneira correta.

Comment: Boa resposta. Também faço isso, se o bloco precisa de explicação ele faz algo "à parte" se faz algo à parte pode ser removido para um método.

Comment: @Selma Realmente complicado :/ Mas me diga, você separaria criando novos métodos que só serão usados no processamento desse método?

Comment: Sim, nessa caso o objetivo é tornar o código mais legível e não necessariamente reaproveitável. Esse é um dos objetivos de se quebrar o código em pedaços menores, isso facilita a futura manutenção.